# Swift code: how to launch a specific view controller after receiving a remote push notification

Tags: ios

In Swift, my **main.storyboard** had 2 view controllers (`mainVC`, `secondVC`), both embedded in their navigation controller. When receiving a remote push notification, how do I change code in `AppDelegate` to have the `secondV`C view controller launch everytime. I currently have code in post the notification in `didReceiveRemoteNotification`, and have code in the `secondVC` to add observer

In `AppDelegate.swift`, my code is as follows:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool
{
    var type = UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Sound
    var setting = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: type, categories: nil)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(setting)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications()
    return true
}
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("MyNotificationType", object: nil, userInfo: userInfo)

}
```

In the `secondVC`, I have code as follows:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    println("viewWillAppear()")
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "AuthenticateWithTouchID:", name: "MyNotificationType", object: nil)
}
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    println("viewWillDISAPPER")
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: "MyNotificationType", object: nil)
}
```

Comment: Are they embedded in a navigation controller?

Comment: Yes both view controller (mainVC, secondVC) are embedded in navigation controller. When remote notification come in, my app launches the top view controller, mainVC, but I need it to launch the secondVC. Thanks for looking in.

Comment: My storyboard is as follow (don't know how to copy the pictures out from Xcode.. kinda new to Xcode).. so it looks like this:

Comment: —> Navigation Controller view  —> mainVC  ——> Navigation Controller View  —> secondVC

Answer (score 1):

This should work. Your UINavigationController's viewControllers property is an array of all the view controllers embedded in the navigation controller. So if you want your second vc, you access it like a typical array, so viewControllers[1]

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {

    var navController:UINavigationController = self.window?.rootViewController as! UINavigationController

    if navController.viewControllers != nil {
        var vc:CustomViewController = navController.viewControllers[1] as! CustomViewController
        navController.presentViewController(vc, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: It make sense for your solution, but I am getting a run-time fatal error: Array index out of range. I assumed from your suggestion solution that "CustomViewController" is the class "secondVC" from my code, which represent the second view controller. Thanks for any advice.

Comment: I printed out navController.viewControllers.count, and getting only 1. That is strange. My storyboard is as:—> Navigation Controller view —> mainVC ——> Navigation Controller View —> secondVC. I don't know why it is not returning 2 view controllers..

Comment: Why do you have two navigation controllers on your storyboard? That is most likely the problem. Each VC doesn't need its own Navigation Controller. Unless you have a tab bar controller somewhere in there, you should be able to controller all of your vc's with one Navigation Controller. Navigation Controller view --> mainVC --> secondVC

Comment: The suggestion code doesn't work for me. Thanks for comments.